# Nested object being deleted on second time through function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a function that gets called every time a Backbone collection updates.  It takes some JSON and maps it so that there is some more data, basically a parse function.  On page load everything works fine.  Not only does `hU.data` exist when it is logged but when you look at each object in `_this.treeData`, everything exists as well when it is logged.

The problem happens when I fetch again (on a user action).  The collection gets updated and when `modifyData` gets called, `hU.data` exists just fine when it is logged.  However, the data attribute on each object in `_this.treeData` no longer exists.  The base object is in `_this.treeData` (text, name, id, parent, active), but `.data` with (parent, id, name, role, addHTML) no longer exists.  It is the case of the disappearing nested object.  I am at my wit's end trying to solve this.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

`_this.treeData` is a variable stored on the Backbone view.  Maybe the problem lies within that?  Is there a memory issue I am missing?

Here it is:

```
modifyData: function () {
        var _this = this;

        var userData = this.collection.toJSON()

        _this.treeData = [];

        _this.treeData = _.map(_.reject(userData, function (u) {
            return u.parent_id === null;
        }), function (u) {
            var hU = {};
            hU.text = u.name;
            hU.id = u.id;
            hU.parent = u.parent_id === 'root' ? '#' : u.parent_id;
            hU.active = u.active;

            if (u.parent_id === 'root') {
                var parent = {
                    name: 'Root'
                }
            } else {
                var parent = _.findWhere(userData, {id: u.parent_id});
            }

            hU.data = {
                parent: parent,
                id: u.id,
                name: u.name,
                role: u.user_role_name,
                addHTML: _this.hierarchyIndivTemplate //This is a function
            };
            console.log(hU.data);

            return hU;
        });
        console.log(_this.treeData);

    },
```

Comment: Any chance of reproducing the problem on jsfiddle.net or somewhere else that we can watch it happen?

Comment: Hmm, it's inside of a proprietary project with lots of dependencies built around it.  I know that the code is syntactically correct and two of the devs I work with spent about an hour on it.  I can try to replicate it on jsfiddle but I sincerely doubt that outside of my stack it will break.  If you have any more theoretical advice to try or direction to go I would be interested.  Otherwise I'll try to get more info.

Comment: Just the usual: step through it with a debugger, make sure `this` is what you expect it to be, look out for accidental reference sharing, ...

Comment: Yes I've done all this.  Thanks for the help, I will keep attempting and let you know.